# Correctly (not) disposing of singleton Spring beans

Tags: java, spring

Consider the case where I have a Spring `Service` bean, which depends on other beans that may expose the `AutoCloseable` interface. I'll ask this question generically and will later explain my specific need.

```
public class ServiceBean {

    @Autowired private ResourceBean resource; //Resource is Closeable

}
```

According to configuration, under certain configurations `Resource` is a global singleton, and in other cases it is a prototype. Since I am writing a library, I was asked to provide degrees of flexibility.

If `resource` is a singleton, it should never be `close()`d until the ApplicationContext is shut down. Otherwise, if `resource` was created prototypely for my instance of `ServiceBean` (which **is** a prototype, I know this by design), then it *shall* be disposed (`close()`d) when the lifecycle of `ServiceBean` ends.

### Step 1: make ServiceBean closeable

Not a bad thing to do. Best practices in programming say that when your class depends on disposable resources, it should be declared disposable and included in try-with-resources blocks

```
public class ServiceBean implements AutoCloseable {

    @Autowired private ResourceBean resource; //Resource is Closeable

    public void close() throws Exception {
        resource.close(); //what the!!!
    }    
}
```

The problem with this setup is that if resource is a prototype, it will be closed on first instance.

Spring provides methods `isPrototype` and `isSingleton` that take String as argument, so I deduce they are meant for bean names, which I don't (want) to know in this context

Question: what should be the correct way to dispose prototype resources in prototype beans? Spring AFAIK disposes only of singletons when ApplicationContext shuts down

### My specific case

I have a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to inject. It may be a singleton or prototype object, and the `shutdown` is useful to clear the pool from outstanding threads

Comment: I like the question but it would have been a lot more succint to simply ask "Do Spring beans support AutoCloseable" :)

Comment: This is what `@PreDestroy` is for.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you don't create it (or control the creation) don't destroy it because you don't know the lifecycle. The same applies to `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. If you have a method that uses an `InputStream` that shouldn't close it because it doesn't own it. The same applies here. Either let it be a singleton (and spring will manage it) or use a properly scoped proxy (which will be closed when the scope ends).

Comment: @drekbour I think there is quite of a difference. I know already that Spring "supports" AutoCloseable for the singletons, but we are talking about prototypes given away into the wild of the code

Comment: @M.Deinum could you expand into an answer? Actually, that might be what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I have come with an idea (a mad idea, not yet tested).

The injected resource bean could leverage the `BeanFactory<>` class.

1. Declare `Resource` by means of a factory

   public class ResourceBeanFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean
2. Parameterize the singletonness

AbstractFactoryBean exposes [`isSingleton`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AbstractFactoryBean.html#isSingleton--)

3. Wrap the returned bean into a non-closeable when the bean is singleton

   protected ResourceBean createInstance() {

   ```
    return isSingleton() ? myBean : wrapNonCloseable(myBean);
   ```

   }

Where `myBean` is the instance you would have created normally, and `wrapNonCloseable` is a utility  method that extends the `close` method to do nothing

```
protected MyResourceBean wrapNonCloseable(MyResourceBean bean) {
    return new MyResourceBean()
    {
        //Delegate all methods to the original bean
        public void close(){}
    }
}
```